# what is the best way to handle json in monotouch

Tags: iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

what are the best ways to handle json in monotouch.  I've seen JSON.net but could not get it to compile in the latest monodevelop.  Are there any other libraries or how are people handling this. Are there any guides out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just discovered that the new monotouch has included a namespace called System.Json.  I didn't see this off the bat since i have never seen it in dotnet before so i wasn't looking for it, but this does the trick very nicely of what i was looking for, hope this helps someone else...

Answer (score 0):

I looks like JSON.net used to work with Mono, at least if not currently http://json.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=77026. Not sure if the WCF JSON serialization is up to snuff in Mono or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/) successfully on Mono. It should work with MonoTouch as well.